# Grunt + usemin, how to include one HTML file in another?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I have a `head.html` file that includes all of my bundles:

```
<!-- build.js(.) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/script1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/script2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I need this file to be separate because I want to use the generated tags to the bundles on legacy parts of my site that aren't part of the app I'm building.

I would then like my `index.html` to do something like this:

```
<head>
  <!-- include:head.html -->
</head>
```

grunt-usemin doesn't seem to support this directive. Any ideas on how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Use [grunt-includes](https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes) and add this to the Gruntfile:

```
includes: {
    files: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        dest: '.'
    }
},
```

Then add an `'includes'` step after the `copy` step in the build task.